# Exporting Wordpress Database from GCP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-compute-engine, gcp

I am trying to create a local replica of wordpress database by exporting it on gcloud console (after logged in via gcloud compute ssh)  but facing this problem. Is there a way out to resolve this or is it prohibited from GCP ?

**atul7911@my-wordpress-1-vm:~$ mysqldump -u wordpress -p wordpress > data-dump.sql**

**mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces**

regards
Atul Vaish

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , seems trivial , after using root login and password, it resolved

**mysqldump -u root -p wordpress > data-dump.sql**